# Rotation invariant multiple template occurrence in image Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, template-matching

I have various template images and one big image with multiple ocurrence of each template in it, but are rotated.

I have tried with SIFT and SURF but only work with one ocurrence of each template and matchTemplate is not rotation invariant. I am programming in C++.

Please, could you give me any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? specially the declarations of the detectors, descriptors and matchers would be useful.

Comment: cant you detect the first occurance with SIFT/SURF, remove those features and try to detect the 2nd one etc?? edit: ok, it only works if exactly one occurance of total is in the image, because best matches will be mixed between multiple occurances. That can be fixed with some heuristic I guess

Comment: Mat plantilla = imread("PlantillaMujer.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    OrbFeatureDetector featureDetector(400);
    vector<KeyPoint> tempKeypoints, imKeypoints;
    featureDetector.detect(plantilla,tempKeypoints);
    featureDetector.detect(imagen,imKeypoints);
    OrbDescriptorExtractor featureExtractor;
    Mat tempDescriptors, imDescriptors;
    featureExtractor.compute(plantilla, tempKeypoints, tempDescriptors);
    featureExtractor.compute(imagen, imKeypoints, imDescriptors);

Comment: vector<DMatch> matches;
    BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2);
    matcher.match(tempDescriptors,imDescriptors,matches);
    Mat img_matches;

    drawMatches(plantilla, tempKeypoints, imagen, imKeypoints, matches, img_matches);
    imwrite("matches.jpg", img_matches);

Comment: I have multiple occurrences in my image. I have thought in firstly identify ROIs in my image and after use SURF/SIFT only in the ROIs detected but I don't know how I could find ROIs in my image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use log-polar template matching.

You can find more explanation here: http://www-cs.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/pub/icip00.pdf

In this paper described method for finding maximum correlated template. But with small modifications it can be used to find multiple occurrences of template.